# dao property from vb to mfc

Tags: mfc, vb6, ado, dao

i have implemented vb functionality in c++ i have replace below logic in c++ but it is giving issue :

i have to convert from VB to c++ and the code in c++ is crashing when getting property.

**Original VB code:**

```
For Each loTDef In aoDBUser.TableDefs

          Set loProp = Nothing
          On Error Resume Next
          Set loProp = loTDef.Properties("Description")

          If Not loProp Is Nothing Then
               If loProp.Value = TEMP_TABLE Then
               End If
          End If
     Next
```

**New C++ code:**

```
CString test::Property()
{
    //
    // OVERVIEW:
    // Get the value for the given Custom Property
    //
    DAOProperties *pColProp = NULL;
    DAOProperty *pProp = NULL;

    CDaoDatabase cDBase;
    cDBase.Open(CV_GetUserDatabasePath(_T("TEST.mdb")));

    CString strDbVer;
    DAOProperties* pPrp = 0;
    DAOProperty* pRev = 0;
    try
    {
        if ( !cDBase.IsOpen() )
            return(_T(""));

        DAO_CHECK(cDBase.m_pDAODatabase->get_Properties(&pPrp));
        if ( pPrp != 0 )
        {
            COleVariant varRevVal;
            COleVariant varName(_T("Description"), VT_BSTRT);

            DAO_CHECK(pPrp->get_Item(varName, &pRev));//crashing going to catch 

            if (pRev != 0)
            {
                DAO_CHECK(pRev->get_Value(&varRevVal));
                pRev->Release();
                pRev = 0;
            }
            pPrp->Release();
            pPrp = 0;

            strDbVer = V_BSTRT(&varRevVal);
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {

    }

    cDBase.Close();
}
```

some how it is crashing in      `DAO_CHECK(pPrp->get_Item(varName, &pRev));`

But I cannot figure out why this occurs.

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting when it "crashes" ?

Comment: u mean getlasterror u want me to do dao property is returning NULL